# Fluentvalidation 6.4.1.0 support me with Incorrect regex

Tags: regex, fluentvalidation

In my case, i want to validate for url image, some url is valid but result is wrong.
Eg: link image is "https://fuvitech.online/wpcontent/uploads/2021/02/bta16600brg.jpg" or "https://fuvitech.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/bta16-600brg.jpg" reponse "The image link is not in the correct format".

My code here:

```
RuleFor(product => product.Images)
            .Length(1, 3000).WithMessage(Labels.importProduct_ExceedDescription, p => ImportHelpers.GetColumnName(typeof(ProductEntity).GetProperty(nameof(p.Images))))
            .Matches(@"^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/){1}?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$").WithMessage(Labels.importProduct_UrlNotCorrect, p => ImportHelpers.GetColumnName(typeof(ProductEntity).GetProperty(nameof(p.Images))));
```

Please help me where the above regex is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @SaSkY answer my question.
I found my mistake.
This source [*.[a-z]{2,5}] only allows domain extensions from 2-5 characters. Example [.com] is valid. But in my case [.online] was not valid.
I changed to [*.[a-z]{1,10}].

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**NOTE** the following regex pattern may trigger false positives and also may ignore valid image URLs, because it is very difficult to validate whether a given URL is valid.

```
^https?:\/\/(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+|[A-Za-z0-9]{2,})\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}(?::\d+)?\/(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+)?\/)+|)[\w-]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` the start of a line/string.
- `https?:\/\/` match `http` with an optional letter `s`, followed by `://`.
- `(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+|[A-Za-z0-9]{2,})\.)+` This will match things like `foo-foo.bar-bar.`, `foo.bar-bar.` and `foo.`
- `[A-Za-z]{2,}` this will match the TLD part, e.g., `com`, `org`, this part with the previous part will match things like `foo-foo.bar-bar.com`, `foo.bar-bar.com` or `foo.com`.
- `(?::\d+)?` optional group of (a colon `:` followed by one or more digits) for port part.
- `\/(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)+)?\/)+|)` this check for two things, the first one is  `/uploads/public-images/`, `/uploads/images/`, the second one is a single `/`.
- `[\w-]+` this part for the file name, e.g., `bta16-600brg`.
- `\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png)` you can add here multiple extensions, you can allow uppercase letters by using for example, `[Jj][Pp][Gg]` for `jpg`.
- `$` the end of the line/string.

See [regex demo](https://regexr.com/75u6s)